# using wget (or other) download highest file version from dropbox

Tags: dropbox, wget

I use the windows variant of wget for scripted downloads of various files but was wondering if it could achieve the following.

Where I work, new versions of the software are regularly released into the company dropbox. I am tasked with making a script that can interrogate the versioning of the file name in the dropbox folder and if its a newer file version than the one currently in the folder where the script was run, it will download and update the file. Kind of like "check for update" kind of thing (newer file version found, downloading, please wait)

Is this possible with Wget or would I need a different program altogether?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will need using dropbox API. Read in https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/overview may can help.